# finding emrips with python, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

> An Emirp is a prime number whose reversal is also a prime. For
>   example, 17 is a prime and 71 is a prime, so 17 and 71 are emirps.
>   Write a program that prints out the first N emirps, five on each line.
>
> Calculate the first N emirp (prime, spelled backwards) numbers, where
>   N is a positive number that the user provides as input.
>
> Implementation Details
>
> You are required to make use of 2 functions (which you must write).
>
> isPrime(value)  # Returns true if value is a prime number. reverse
>   (value) # Returns the reverse of the value (i.e. if value is 35,
>   returns 53). You should use these functions in conjunction with logic
>   in your main part of the program, to perform the computation of N
>   emirps and print them out according to the screenshot below.
>
> The general outline for your program would be as follows:
>
> Step 1: Ask user for positive number (input validation) Step 2:
>   Initialize a variable Test to 2 Step 3: While # emirps found is less
>   than the input:
>           Call isPrime with Test, and call it again with reverse(Test). 
>           If both are prime, print and increment number of emirps found. Test++ Hint - to reverse the number, turn it into a string and then
>   reverse the string. Then turn it back into an int!

MY CODE:

```
n = 0
count = 0
i = 1
def isPrime(value):
    test = 2
    count = 0
    while(test < value):
        if( value % test == 0):
            count+=count
            test+=test
    if(count == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def reverse(value):
    reverse = 0
    while(value > 0):
        reverse = reverse * 10 + (value % 10)
        value = value / 10
    return reverse

n = float(input("Please enter a positive number: "))

while(count < n):
    i+=i;
    if(isPrime(i)):
        if(isPrime(reverse(i))):
                print("i" + "\n")
                count+=count
        if((count % (5)) == 0 ):
                print("\n")
```

where are the mistakes?

UPDATED CODE BUT STILL NOT RUNNING:

```
    n = 0
    count = 0
    i = 1
    def isPrime(value):
     test = 2
    while(test < value):
        if( value % test != 0):
            test +=1
        else:
            return 0

def reverse(value):
    return int(str(value)[::-1])

i = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
count = 0
while(count < 5):
    if(isPrime(i)):
        if(isPrime(reverse(i))):
                print(str(i) + "\n")
                count += 1
                i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    else:
        i +=1
```

Comment: This is not a place for you to dump homework when you get tired of working on it yourself.

Comment: How do you know it's not running?   Please give more information

Comment: Your updated isPrime never returns 1.  You left out the last return statement.

Comment: I updated and the code runs, but when I type in "1" I receive 1, 3, 5,7. The code should print the first 1 emrip. I am not sure what it is printing

Comment: It prints the first five emirp from the imput int. I thought that you wanted to generate this. If you want to print only the first emirp you can adjust the code easily.

Comment: The entered number is the number you want to start testing from, not the number of emrip's you want.   You have hardcoded the number of emrip's you want as 5.   When I run the code and enter 1, I get 1,2,3,5,7

Comment: 1 should print the first emrip, 25 should print the first 25 emrips etc :)

Comment: how can i fix this? I tried to put i in the place of 5 and get an error

Comment: Something like: count = int(input("")) i=1 while(count>0)  And decriment count instead of increment

Comment: And you should select Peter's answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I am still having issues with the code

Comment: Stop saying issues and give more information.

Comment: count = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
i = 1
while(count > 0):
    if(isPrime(i)):
        if(isPrime(reverse(i))):
                print(str(i) + "\n")
                count -= 1

Comment: n = 0
count = 0
i = 1
def isPrime(value):
    test = 2
    while(test < value):
        if( value % test != 0):
            test +=1
        else:
            return 0
    return 1

def reverse(value):
    return int(str(value)[::-1])

count = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
i = 1
while(count > 0):
    if(isPrime(i)):
        if(isPrime(reverse(i))):
            print(str(i) + "\n")
            count -= count
        else:
            i += 1
    else:
        i +=1
the only thing that prints out is "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code. I altered the function `isPrime`. There is among other no need for `count` here and if you want to increment `test` by `1` every loop use `test +=1`:

```
def isPrime(value):
test = 2
while(test < value):
    if( value % test != 0):
        test +=1
    else:
        return 0
return 1
```

There is an easy way to reverse digits by making `value` a string in reversed order and to convert this into an integer:

```
def reverse(value):
    return int(str(value)[::-1])
```

You among other have to assign the input to `i`. `n` in your code is a constant `5`. You have to increment `i` by one in any condition and increment the count by one if `i` is an emirp only:

```
i = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
count = 0
while(count < 5):  
    if(isPrime(i)):
        if(isPrime(reverse(i))):
                print(str(i) + "\n")
                count += 1
                i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    else:
        i +=1
```

Comment: Your second isPrime never returns 1.  You left out the last statement.

Comment: Yes it runs fine and indent your update properly as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
    def emrip_no(num):
    i=0
    j=0
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        a=0
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            if(i%j==0):
                a+=1
    if(a==2):
        print("Number is a prime number")
        k=0
        l=0
        rv=0
        while(num!=0):
            r=num%10
            rv=(rv*10)+r
            num=num//10
        print("It's reverse is: ",rv)
        for k in range(1,rv+1):
            b=0
            for l in range(1,k+1):
                if(k%l==0):
                    b+=1
        if(b==2):
            print("It's reverse is also a prime number")
        else:
            print("It's reverse is not a prime number")

n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
emrip_no(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is almost 5.5 years old) with existing answers. See [answer].